# Does the change event fire on documentready?

Tags: jquery, onchange, document-ready

## What I have:

I have two text boxes. When the page loads, the value of the first text box is applied to the second.

## What I need:

I need the change event to fire when the page loads.

## My code:

**HTML:**

```
a: <input type="text" id="a" value="x" />
b: <input type="text" id="b" value="y" />
```

**JQuery:**

```
// Apply value of #a to #b and fire change event...
$('#b').val($('#a').val()).change();

// Listen for the change and alert...
$('#b').on('change', function() {
    alert("Change event fired on load.");
});
```

**JSFiddle:**

For your convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/clarusdignus/rHYLM/

## My problem:

The change event is not firing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event handlers are attached after the event is fired by code

First should be

```
  // Listen for the change and alert...
$('#b').on('change', function() {
    alert("Change event fired on load.");
});

// Apply value of #a to #b and fire change event...
$('#b').val($('#a').val()).change();
```

Second should be

```
// Listen for the change and alert...
$('#b').on('change', function() {
    alert("Change event fired on load.");
});

// Apply value of #a to #b and fire change event...
$('#b').val($('#a').val()).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Thank you. This works, the alert boxes are now producing. http://jsfiddle.net/clarusdignus/rHYLM/4/

Answer (score 1):

You should **trigger** the change event. So...

```
$('#b').val($('#a').val()).trigger('change');
```

Also, you need to tell JavaScript to exec these lines *after* the document is loaded (ready). This can be done wrapping your code inside this:

> $(function() {   /* your code */  });

Wich is a simplifyed version of:

> $( document ).ready(function() { ... });

Comment: No need for `.trigger()` - `.change()` will work just as well

Comment: I know, but the idea was to show Clarus he need to trigger a event handler.

Comment: I've applied `.trigger()` but it's had no effect. Please review this forked JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/clarusdignus/TFAvd/1/

Comment: Regarding your edit, yes, my local code is already wrapped within the necessary function. i.e. `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`. As per the JSFiddles I provided, from what I can tell, it automatically applies the document ready function.

Comment: @tymeJV - Please refer to the provided JSFiddle in my question. .change() is not producing the desired effect.

Comment: Well, the code (your and mine) is working. Does it work for you on JSFiddle?

Comment: It doesn't work for me locally nor does it work on JSFiddle. Are you unable to view JSFiddle?

Comment: It work for me.. local and in JSFiddle. Is "b" showing the content of "a"? Maybe you disabled the alerts in your browser..

Comment: Even though alerts are not disabled, following your instruction, I've viewed the code on three different browsers. #b is indeed showing the content of #a however the alert box is not being presented. I know I'm being pedantic but can you actually say (as in copy and paste back to me) "I've produced and seen the alert box both locally and in JSFiddle."