# Why do browsers inconsistently render incorrectly ordered jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

## Context:

I recently executed a block of jQuery code in which I incorrectly applied positioned on event handler before the event. The objective of the code was to produce an alert box on a change event.

## Observation:

On my end, the alert box did not execute in the latest versions of FF, Chrome and IE. Other StackOverflow members (via live chat and [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818727/does-the-change-event-fire-on-documentready)) confirmed to me that the alert box executed on their end (across a variety of browsers) whereas others observed that the alert boxes did not.

## Code:

**Incorrectly ordered code:**

```
//Event handler
$('#b').val($('#a').val()).change();
//Event
$('#b').on('change', function() {
    alert("Change event fired on load.");
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/clarusdignus/rHYLM/

**Correctly ordered code:**

```
//Event
$('#b').on('change', function() {
    alert("Change event fired on load.");
});
//Event handler
$('#b').val($('#a').val()).change();
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/clarusdignus/rHYLM/4/

## My question:

Why do browsers inconsistently render incorrect jQuery with regards to incorrectly ordered event handlers and events?

Comment: Your first line won't fire the `.change()` event because you're running it before the next line binds the handler.

Comment: Do these other members know what alert to look for? Do the expect it when the page loads? Are they testing it correctly? It doesn't matter what other users say they experience. What do you find? Does it sometimes work for you and other times not?

Comment: Can anyone explain why this question has been down-voted twice? My question is of pertinence to the behavior of JSFiddle regarding how it inconsistently opted to produce and not produce alerts. It's a legitimate question, one that as of yet, has not been directly answered and one not to be confused with the question I linked to.

Comment: @cookiemonster - Affirmative, affirmative and affirmative. I've already outlined the answer to your fourth question in my question and as for the fifth, my results were consistent in that the alert boxes were never presented. All of this aside, I acknowledge your point about not relying on the findings of others. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @ClarusDignus It's a question for JS Fiddle support; not to mention that we don't do well for problems on other sites; we do well with programming issues you face.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - Hi George. The edited form of the question (to which you're replying) clearly stipulates that the anomaly is not proprietary to JSFiddle (the JSFiddle links are simply examples). The anomaly can be reproduced when the code is executed in standard HTML documents locally or on a hosted server. The original version of my question outlined this though my question title was misleading and therefore edited. It's probably best to delete the question. Though I've persisted because I feel it's a legitimate question, it's not my intention to cause confusion or annoyance.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - This doesn't fall under the category of "programming issues you face" as it doesn't impact my work-flow in any way. It's simply a point of curiosity. Please delete. Apologies.

Answer (score 2):

According to w3 standard change event should propagate in bubble order.All do that except IE<9 
Probably this is why there is inconsistency in firing of change event.